# Cannot cast from Object to int JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, front-end, java-ee-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando JSP e servelt em que quero pegar a quantidade total de registros da minha tabela tb_motorista,criei uma servelt em que passei o método que faz a consulta e criei uma sessão mas ao pegar a sessão criada na servelet e colocar na pagina listaMotorista2 ele aparece o seguinte erro.`An error occurred at line: 47 in the jsp file: /listaMotoristas2.jsp Cannot cast from Object to int`

```
 public int totalRegistros(){

     try {
        con = Conecta.conexao();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conecta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


            try {

       String sql="Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_motorista";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();     

       ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);    
        rs.next();
        int totalRegistros=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("contaRegistros"));
        return totalRegistros;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);

}
            return 0;
}

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
 HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     MotoristasDAO dao= new MotoristasDAO();

     try {

          int totalMotorista=dao.totalRegistros();

     request.setAttribute("totalMotoristas", totalMotorista);

     RequestDispatcher rd= 
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/listaMotoristas2.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

   }

            <%

    int totalRegistros= (int) request.getAttribute("totalMotorista");//Cannot cast from Object to int


          %>
```

Comment: Se você inserir um `System.out.println(rs.getString("contaRegistros"));`, qual é o resultado? Esse output poderia ficar logo a seguir o `rs.next();`

Comment: Weslley Tavares ele retorna o numero de registros 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.setAttribute("totalMotoristas", totalMotorista);
```

Os parâmetros de HttpServletRequest.setAttribute() são String e Object.
totalMotorista é int, que não é Object e sim um tipo primitivo.

Mude para Integer nos pontos:

```
- public Integer totalRegistros(){
- Integer totalRegistros=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("contaRegistros"));
- Integer totalMotorista=dao.totalRegistros();
```

Comment: funcionou aqui obrigado

Comment: Então dá um voto ;-)